# Error in ng-bootstrap.js ng-bootstrap Angular 6

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I've just installed ng-bootstrap in my Angular project and after that I've include its modules. But my CLI shows me an error.

> "WARNING in
>   ./node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/fesm5/ng-bootstrap.js
>   9853:57-75 "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in
>   '@angular/core'"

app.module

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {NgbPaginationModule, NgbAlertModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgxPaginationModule,
    NgbModule,
    NgbPaginationModule,
    NgbAlertModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "eastlaw",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.0.0-rc.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/router": "^4.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "^4.0.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^4.0.0",
    "ngx-slick": "^0.2.1",
    "ngx-slick-carousel": "^0.4.4",
    "npm": "^6.9.2",
    "rxjs": "6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe an issue of version compatibility!

Comment: so what I've to do? @PrashantPimpale

Comment: Since Angular v6 `ɵɵdefineInjectable` is used instead of `defineInjectable`. What versions do you use?

Comment: @Martin2904 please check question again.

Comment: i faced the same issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are running an Angular 6 app make sure you have installed ng-bootstrap 3.x.x. If you really need to use that specific version of ng-bootstrap consider upgrading your Angular version. 
For more details on compatibility check the [docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started).

Comment: how can I install 3.x.x version from cli?

Comment: if you are using npm and wants to install release 3.3.1 try this `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@3.3.1`.

Comment: do you have any example of pagination in this (3.3.1) version ?

Comment: I am not using ng-bootstrap at the moment, and I don't have an example. My recommendation is that, if you can, update angular and ng-bootstrap to the latest version. The [docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination/overview) for the ng-bootstrap gives you some example that can help. Try making something small and simple work in a stackblitz than apply that to your project.

Answer (score 3):

get update to your angular CLI to reach the list of minimal required versions of Angular and Bootstrap CSS for ng-bootstrap

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

go to this page and read the Dependencies 
 https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started#installation

to check your angular version

```
ng -v
```